# Why doesn't the cringely feed work in iTunes

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I'm trying to subscribe to this feed using iTunes on a Mac, and it keeps telling me it is an invalid podcast URL.

http://www.cringely.com/feed/podcast/

I looked at the feed, and it looks fine. Safari recognizes it and even shows me the mp3 attachments, why won't iTunes recognize it?

Comment: doesn't cringely hate itunes?  been a while since i've followed him...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be malformed XML or something. Likely nothing you can do about it on your end. Google Chrome complains about an error:

[image]